# Should I provide an explicit back button in my view?

Tags: android

When an application has a single view, the Back button probably resumes whatever previous application was running/suspended. I'm tempted to provide an explicit button which says 'Back' right there on the UI ...

Should I provide an explicit back button in my view, or should I simply override the navigation button provided by the OS? My gut says the latter would be counter-intuitive. Are there any recommendations on this by the android community?

Comment: What is it your back button should do? Since you want to override the default behaviour, it must be something different. Without knowing that, there can't be any realistic answer.

Comment: My back button (on screen) would mimic the behaviour of the h/w back button...

Comment: Then don't build one imho. Not only is it a waste of screen space, it's also pretty counter-intuitive. That hardware back button is always on my phone, I can press that one in my sleep and it works in any app. I surely won't change my habits for one single app. Don't fight working usage patterns. It will just confuse and frustrate your users to some degree *("Whats this back button, there is already one on my phone? So this must have a different function. Click - err wait what?!")*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That entirely depends on your application. Normally, your application is made out of multiple activities (`Activity` objects), and the back button will go to the previous activity.

So if your app has a main menu (activity A), which has a button to go to search (activity B), which will lead to search results (activity C), then pressing the back button on the search page gets you back to the main menu. This is fully automatic, you don't need to write anything for this to work.

That's how Android works, and that's how you should write your app. All Android devices have a device button (physical or on-screen, in case of Honeycomb), so don't waste precious screen real estate on a "back button". Don't be like the iPhone.